# Ad unit Ads of Adsense does not work

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I have approved my AdSense account last month. And the ads are live on my site but the issue is google auto ads shows properly on my site but when I want to create some custom ads on Ads unit and put the code into my site then these custom ads don't show on my site. My site link is   https://devdap.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix your own ads with Google Adsense you should use DFP.
You can set you own priority on how you want to show your ads.